# Error during installation of opencv in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm

```
> opencv-build@0.0.15 install C:\projects\opencvtry\node_modules\opencv-build
> node ./install.js

info install if you want to use an own OpenCV installation set OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD
info install library dir does not exist: C:\projects\opencvtry\node_modules\opencv-build\opencv\build\lib\Release
info install running install script...
ERR! Error: Command failed: cmake --version
'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm WARN opencvtry@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.0.15 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.0.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 9):

Open your terminal.

Step 1 install brew // skip this step if your machine has brew installed.

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null

Step 2 install cMake

> brew install cmake

You can check if cmake installed by

> cmake --version

Answer (score 6):

You need of 'cmake' in your Operative System, es. in Debian/Ubuntu

```
 sudo apt install -y cmake
```

Answer (score 5):

to solve that issue, please download the Cmake installer by following the link:

https://cmake.org/download/

Preferably I would suggest downloading the msi installer if you are windows, and select that it sets the system environment variable for you.

Awesome, that should fix that error.

but if you decide to set the environment variable manually, here is the docs
https://stellar-group.github.io/hpx/docs/html/hpx/manual/build_system/cmake_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say you don't have cmake installed or is not in your path:

'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command

execute "cmake" before "npm install --save opencv4nodejs" and if the command is not found then you catched it.